# Terraform pulling all ARNs from AWS ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Have multiple AWS Accounts with multiple certificates. My goal is to create a list of all Certificate ARNS that have a status as ISSUED. Using a data source with for_each to loop through the variable.

**Facing a problem looping through a map of string to string/maps, and select the one key "arn".**

This is what I have so far.

```
# variables.tf
variable "domains" {
  type = map(any)
}

# dev.tfvars
domains = {
  semantic = "semantic"
  embedding = "embedding-svc"
}

data "aws_acm_certificate" "domains" {
  for_each = var.domains
  domain = "${each.value}.${var.environment}.aws.mydomain.net"
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
  most_recent = true
}
```

The data source will loop through the variable `var.domains` and creates a map from the key in the domains variable to the result.

Output of the data source looks like the below.

```
# outputs.tf
output "acm" {
  value = data.aws_acm_certificate.domains.*
}
```

Returns

```yaml
acm = {
  "semantic" = {
    "arn" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/22e77818-075d-4ffd-8f13-cbf91b801198"
    "domain" = "semantic.aws.mydomain.net"
    "id" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/22e77818-075d-4ffd-8f13-cbf91b801198"
    "key_types" = toset(null) /* of string */
    "most_recent" = true
    "status" = "ISSUED"
    "statuses" = tolist([
      "ISSUED",
    ])
    "tags" = tomap({})
    "types" = tolist(null) /* of string */
  }
  "embedding" = {
    "arn" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/edd30a0b-f838-4bc9-8660-bd691e635df9"
    "domain" = "embedding-svc.aws.mydomain.net"
    "id" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/edd30a0b-f838-4bc9-8660-bd691e635df9"
    "key_types" = toset(null) /* of string */
    "most_recent" = true
    "status" = "ISSUED"
    "statuses" = tolist([
      "ISSUED",
    ])
    "tags" = tomap({})
    "types" = tolist(null) /* of string */
  }
}
```

I have tried to loop through the data source to select only the "arn" key, but this fails.

```
locals {
  certificates = [
    for acm_mapping in data.aws_acm_certificate.domains : [
      for acm in acm_mapping : acm # ugh.. acm.arn breaks..
    ]
  ]
}

output "acm2" {
  value = {
    certificates = local.certificates
  }
}
```

This returns the same thing as the above output but in a list form without the keys.

```yaml
acm2 = {
  "certificates" = [
    [
      "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/22e77818-075d-4ffd-8f13-cbf91b801198",
      "davinci.dev.aws.jpmchase.net",
      "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/22e77818-075d-4ffd-8f13-cbf91b801198",
      toset(null) /* of string */,
      true,
      "ISSUED",
      tolist([
        "ISSUED",
      ]),
      tomap({}),
      tolist(null) /* of string */,
    ],
    [
      "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/edd30a0b-f838-4bc9-8660-bd691e635df9",
      "ted.dev.aws.jpmchase.net",
      "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/edd30a0b-f838-4bc9-8660-bd691e635df9",
      toset(null) /* of string */,
      true,
      "ISSUED",
      tolist([
        "ISSUED",
      ]),
      tomap({}),
      tolist(null) /* of string */,
    ],
  ]
}
```

If I want to select acm.arn in the for loop I get the following error. Trimmed the error as it repeats for each item in the map.

```
?[1m?[31mError: ?[0m?[0m?[1mUnsupported attribute?[0m

?[0m  on outputs.tf line 24, in locals:
  24:       for acm in acm_mapping : acm?[4m.arn?[0m
?[0m
This value does not have any attributes.
?[0m?[0m
?[31m
?[1m?[31mError: ?[0m?[0m?[1mMissing map element?[0m

?[0m  on outputs.tf line 24, in locals:
  24:       for acm in acm_mapping : acm?[4m.arn?[0m
?[0m
This map does not have an element with the key "arn".
?[0m?[0m
?[31m
?[1m?[31mError: ?[0m?[0m?[1mAttempt to get attribute from null value?[0m


?[0m  on outputs.tf line 24, in locals:
  24:       for acm in acm_mapping : acm?[4m.arn?[0m
?[0m
This value does not have any attributes.
?[0m?[0m
?[31m
?[1m?[31mError: ?[0m?[0m?[1mAttempt to get attribute from null value?[0m
Run Status: ?[37;1merrored?[0m
ERROR: error running apply: run errored
```

**The output I am seeking is the below.**

```
certificates = [
   "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/22e77818-075d-4ffd-8f13-cbf91b801198", 
   "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/edd30a0b-f838-4bc9-8660-bd691e635df9"
]
```

Appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output provided, using the [`values` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values) should do the trick:

```
output "acm" {
  value = values(data.aws_acm_certificate.domains)[*].arn
}
```

Using local variables with the output from the question, this is the expected result:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + acm = [
      + "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/edd30a0b-f838-4bc9-8660-bd691e635df9",
      + "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:AWS_ACCOUNT:certificate/22e77818-075d-4ffd-8f13-cbf91b801198",
    ]
```

Comment: Making this look easy @Marko E, thanks this is great. Why can't we do this? `data.aws_acm_certificate.domains[*].arn`, if we were to change the variable to a different type, would that create a valid splat expression?

Comment: The splat expression is used for list/set/tuple-type results. You used `for_each` with the data source, which means the result will be a map of key/value pairs. More info: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat#splat-expressions-with-maps.